# how to call the returned value from a function? and how does it work on this script? (python)

Tags: python, return, compare

although I found many answers to such question, none were on python.
I don't understand what is the logic in this returned code:

```
    def math(a,b):
      result = a+b
      return result 
    result = math(1,2)
    print("you did math", result)
```

the line that I don't understand is line 4.
the thing that I don't get is:
why did we compare `result` to math(1,2)?
more specificaly:
how come that I compare the return value of a function and compare it to the same function?
and how come that this still makes the `result` contain the result in the function itself?
like, I didn't know that the comapring of the return of the same function was even possible.
from what I know myself, your answer will be most beneficial if you will send it by this:
I would like to also know how you find another use of such comparing process, which this use is in  a given as a new script, which as a reuslt shows another way to look at such comparing process in term of its variaty of uses.

Comment: Single equal sign (=) is an assignment operator not a comparison operator. You are assigning whatever is returned from the math function to the result variable.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "compare"? Why do you feel anything is being "compared" in the code snip you shared? The line result = math(1,2) isn't comparing anything - it's taking the output of the function call math(1,2) and assigning it to a variable named "result". There's no comparison happening here...

Comment: what I mean by equal is assignment operator. this is what I ment by that. but I eventually understood my misunderstanding, thus no need for further help.